# Save image data on ajax request MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hi everyone i want to save image data: id ,title and album title on click using ajax.
So here is my model

```
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string albumTitle { get; set; }

    public string photoUrl { get; set;
```

controller

```
  public ActionResult Save()
    {
        return View("Index");
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(int id,string photoUrl, string albumName)
    {
        ps.ID = id;
        ps.photoUrl = photoUrl;
        ps.albumName = albumName;

        return View("Index");
    }
```

and View

```
 @model FlickrApi.Models.FavouritePhotos
<div id="gallery">

</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var url = 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.photosets.getList&api_key=715a9548b42114d69859975d717210cd&user_id=126550680@N04&format=json&jsoncallback=?';
        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            $.each(data.photosets.photoset, function (idx, item) {

                var photosetid = item.id;
                var photosurl = 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&api_key=e6be1bfdf4294482904dce01ac431615&photoset_id=' + photosetid + '&media=photos&format=json&jsoncallback=?&per_page=?';

                // here you would build a new url for each photoset
                // example of how to extract just printing "secret" on right
                $('#gallery').append('<h3 class="echo" id="' + idx + '" >' + item.title._content + '</h3><ul class="gallery photos grp' + idx + '"></ul>');

                // once url is built you would pass to plugin, or make own getJSON request for each set and then parse results same way 'secret' extracted above to insert into page
                $.getJSON(photosurl, function (data) {
                    $.each(data.photoset.photo, function (photoNum, photo) {
                        var photoid = photo.id;
                        var secret = photo.secret;
                        var server = photo.server;
                        var farm = photo.farm;
                        var photo_url = 'http://farm' + farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + server + '/' + photoid + '_' + secret + '_s.jpg';
                        var photo_urlm = 'http://farm' + farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + server + '/' + photoid + '_' + secret + '_m.jpg';
                        $('.photos.grp' + idx).append('<li><a class="example" data-toggle="tooltip"  title="' + photo.title + '"  href="#"><img class="save" src="' + photo_url + '" /></a></li>');
                        //   $('.photos.grp' + idx).css('display','none');
                        $('.photos').css('list-style-type', 'none');
                        $('.example').tooltip(
                        {
                            animation: true,
                        });
                        $('.save').click(function() {
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: '@Url.Action("Save","Home")',
                                data: {id: photo.id, photoUrl:photo_url, ablumName: photo.title}


                            });
                        });
                    });


                });
            });

    });


});
```

Chrome console send me 500 internal server error, i hope someone would help me, i'll be very pleasant for any help, thx. And if anyone need what i'm getting when call ajax to retrieve images here is sample code on jsbin http://jsbin.com/xerojane/5/edit

Comment: Have you checked the cause of the 500 error? How can anyone fix a problem without knowing what the problem is?

Comment: problem is in saving data img, i think i'm make wrong controller or ajax request..

Comment: i think it's try to save all incoming url's, title's when window is ready...

Comment: are you sure `photo.id` is not null or `undefined`?

Comment: yes i'm sure [link](http://s28.postimg.org/3p16y41z1/image.png)